# Stop Android from "reminding" me about updates?

Tags: updates

With the new Android update now avalible, Android has been notifying me each day about updating to the latest version. Each time I press "remind" me later and the notification goes away temporarily. **Is there a way to completely remove this reminder?**

I am running Android 4.4.4

Comment: [Can 4.3 update notification be removed?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54254/can-4-3-update-notification-be-removed?lq=1) also contains suggestions that should still be applicable.

Comment: Yes! Can someone delete this. I can't from my phone.